Can I perform Janabah Ghusl inside the bathroom?
I am in a state of janabah and I was wondering if it is okay to perform Janabah Ghusl inside the bathroom. If it is okay, do I say bismillah and the niyat before I enter the bathroom?

Ghusl is valid in the bathroom. As for your second question: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/23308/can-you-say-bismillah-in-the-bathroom-before-wudu https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/34010/dhikr-remembrance-of-allah-in-the-bathroom-is-it-offensive/ https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9286/can-you-take-allahs-name-in-the-bathroom

Also, welcome to Islam SE. Please read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more info regarding how to ask a proper question on this website.
